# Save multiple objects to single file vb.net

Tags: vb.net, single-file

Greeting,

I am trying to save multiple type of objects to a single file, objects are a custom class that I am able to serializable and another object is a word document that is not being able to serialize via binary.  Is there a way to save multiple objects to one file using vb, also would it be possible to save files like how a docx is saved, that is a .zip renamed as docx but get access to inner objects.

I am trying to do in vb.net.

Comment: BTW, that's docx only, not doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a method to do it manually by way of using System.IO.ZipPackaging and BinarySerialization when necessary.
Thank you.